# problem installing jdk jvm

Tags: jdk

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Comment: Which command did you use?

Comment: And were you trying to install something else at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're already running something to install a package.  Make sure you don't have Ubuntu Software Center or `apt-get` running when you try this.  Also make sure you're using `sudo apt-get` not `apt-get`.